# Show array data according to month

Tags: php, loops

I have array like below.The array data may vary from Jan to Dec for each product

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [SalesYear] => 2018
                [SalesMonth] => July
                [TotalSales] => 1
                [name] => Budweiser Beer 330ml (Pack of 3)
                [code] => BB330
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [SalesYear] => 2018
                [SalesMonth] => August
                [TotalSales] => 2
                [name] => Budweiser Beer 330ml (Pack of 3)
                [code] => BB330
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [SalesYear] => 2018
                [SalesMonth] => September
                [TotalSales] => 16
                [name] => Budweiser Beer 330ml (Pack of 3)
                [code] => BB330
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [SalesYear] => 2018
                [SalesMonth] => August
                [TotalSales] => 11
                [name] => Chicharon 100g
                [code] => CC100
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [SalesYear] => 2018
                [SalesMonth] => September
                [TotalSales] => 3
                [name] => Chicharon 100g
                [code] => CC100
            )

    )
```

Now i want to show each month sale of product :

https://prnt.sc/kysxur

So far this is what I tried

[image]

Thanks

Comment: you can start by using `foreach` loop

Comment: @AlivetoDie yeah i have tried lot

Comment: https://prnt.sc/kyt4lv

Comment: Please dont post pictures of code

Comment: @SanjayKumar  check the answer below and if worked then consider marking the answer. You can vote others if they are useful too. Otherwise your question will be shown as open question for answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = [];
$months = [];
foreach($array as $items) {
   foreach($items as $item) {
       $months[$item['SalesMonth']] = $item['SalesMonth'];
       $result[$item['name']][$item['SalesMonth']] = ($result[$item['name']][$item['SalesMonth']]??0) + $item['TotalSales'];
    }
}
?>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Product</th>
   <?php foreach($months as $month):?>
      <th><?=$month;?></th>
   <?php endforeach;?>
</tr>
<?php foreach($result as $name => $items):?>
    <tr>
       <td><?=$name;?></td>
       <?php foreach($months as $month):?>
           <td><?=$items[$month]??0;?></td>
       <?php endforeach;?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need uksort function but you will need to arrange some things there:

```
uksort($array, function($a1, $a2) {
        $time1 = strtotime($a1);
        $time2 = strtotime($a2);

        return $time1 - $time2;
    });

print_r($ar);
```

and months should be in string